# como resolver error "was not declared in this scope " c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

quería pedirles ayuda ya que estoy recién aprendiendo a programar en c++, y estaba haciendo un ejercicio, cuando me salio el error  "was not declared in this scope" entiendo que este error sale cuando no has declarado la variable o esta mal el tipo de variable que le asignaste pero creo yo que definí bien todo, así que no se donde esta el error este es mi código (Dejare indicado en mayúsculas donde comienzan los errores):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//Definición de variables
    float costoTotal, descTotal, costFinal,preZapatos, preCinturones,preCarteras;
    float totalZapatos,descZapatos,netoZapatos, totalCarteras, descCartera, netoCartera, netoCinturones, porFinal, cantZapatos, cantCinturones, cantCarteras;
    int condContado;
//asignando valor a variables constantes y de proceso
    preZapatos= 22.75;
    preCinturones = 16.75;
    preCarteras= 40;
    descTotal = 0;
    costoTotal= 0;   
    descZapatos = 0;
//Lectura de los datos
    cout << ("Ingrese la cantidad de zapatos que desea comprar") << endl;
    cin >> cantZapatos;
    cout << ("Ingrese la cantidad de cinturones que desea comprar") << endl;
    cin >> cantCinturones;
    cout << ("Ingrese la cantidad de carteras que desea comprar") << endl;
    cin >> cantCarteras;
    cout << ("Ingrese 1 si va a proceder a comprar de contado, ingrese 2 si no") << endl;
    cin >> condContado;

//se toman los pedidos de zapatos
    totalZapatos = (cantZapatos*preZapatos);

/////////////////AQUI SALEN LOS ERRORES////////////////////
    descZapatos = (TotalZapatos*0.20);
    netoZapatos = (TotalZapatos - DescZapatos);
//se toman los pedidos de carteras
    totalCarteras = (cantCarteras * preCarteras); 
    descCartera = totalCarteras * 0.15;
    netoCartera = TotalZapatos - descCartera;
//se toman los pedidos de cinturones
    netoCinturones = (cantCinturones * preCinturones); 
// se suman los totales
    descTotal = descZapatos + descCartera;
    costoTotal = netoZapatos + netoCartera + netoCinturones;
//se evalua si comprara de contado se le aplica un descuento del 17%

//Proceso para los cálculos
    if (condContado==1) {
        // si paga de contado
        porFinal= (costoTotal - descTotal)*0.17;
        descTotal = descTotal + porFinal;
        costFinal = costoTotal - descTotal;
    } else {
     if (condContado==2) {
        //si no paga de contado
        costFinal = costoTotal - descTotal;
     } else {
        cout << ("Error de ingreso de datos") << endl;  
     }
    }
//Impresión de resultados
    cout << ("El costo inicial de esta compra es: $") << endl;
    cout << costoTotal << endl;
    cout << ("El total del descuento que se le aplico es: $") << endl;
    cout << descTotal << endl;
    cout << ("El costo final de esta compra es: $") << endl;
    cout << costFinal << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

y el error que me salta es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero puedan ayudarme y de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Tus variables son diferentes, el compilador diferencia mayúsculas con minúsculas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! justo eso era, un error pequeño y simple pero que me estuvo un buen tiempo revisando todo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error `"was not declared in this scope"`. Hace referencia a que la variable no fue declarada dentro del ***scope*** (alcance) de la función ó bloque.

El alcance en **C++** es por bloque (entre llaves), por lo cual si la variable se declara dentro de llaves, esta dejará de existir al momento de salir de este bloque.

En tu caso puedo ver que es un simple error de mayusculas en el uso de **totalZapatos** y **descZapatos**. 
Tené en cuenta que el compilador es case sensitive, entonces..

***Por ejemplo:***
Si declaramos las variables de esta manera...

```
float totalZapatos,descZapatos;
```

Luego al momento de utilizarla no puedo llamarla

```
TotalZapatos ó DescZapatos
```

Ya que al comenzar con mayúscula el compilador no la reconocerá como la misma variable.

Así quedaría el código!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//Definición de variables
    float costoTotal, descTotal, costFinal,preZapatos, preCinturones,preCarteras;
    float totalZapatos,descZapatos,netoZapatos, totalCarteras, descCartera, netoCartera, netoCinturones, porFinal, cantZapatos, cantCinturones, cantCarteras;
    int condContado;
//asignando valor a variables constantes y de proceso
    preZapatos= 22.75;
    preCinturones = 16.75;
    preCarteras= 40;
    descTotal = 0;
    costoTotal= 0;   
    descZapatos = 0;
//Lectura de los datos
    cout << ("Ingrese la cantidad de zapatos que desea comprar") << endl;
    cin >> cantZapatos;
    cout << ("Ingrese la cantidad de cinturones que desea comprar") << endl;
    cin >> cantCinturones;
    cout << ("Ingrese la cantidad de carteras que desea comprar") << endl;
    cin >> cantCarteras;
    cout << ("Ingrese 1 si va a proceder a comprar de contado, ingrese 2 si no") << endl;
    cin >> condContado;

//se toman los pedidos de zapatos
    totalZapatos = (cantZapatos*preZapatos);

/////////////////AQUI SALEN LOS ERRORES////////////////////
    descZapatos = (totalZapatos*0.20);
    netoZapatos = (totalZapatos - descZapatos);
//se toman los pedidos de carteras
    totalCarteras = (cantCarteras * preCarteras); 
    descCartera = totalCarteras * 0.15;
    netoCartera = totalZapatos - descCartera;
//se toman los pedidos de cinturones
    netoCinturones = (cantCinturones * preCinturones); 
// se suman los totales
    descTotal = descZapatos + descCartera;
    costoTotal = netoZapatos + netoCartera + netoCinturones;
//se evalua si comprara de contado se le aplica un descuento del 17%

//Proceso para los cálculos
    if (condContado==1) {
        // si paga de contado
        porFinal= (costoTotal - descTotal)*0.17;
        descTotal = descTotal + porFinal;
        costFinal = costoTotal - descTotal;
    } else {
     if (condContado==2) {
        //si no paga de contado
        costFinal = costoTotal - descTotal;
     } else {
        cout << ("Error de ingreso de datos") << endl;  
     }
    }
//Impresión de resultados
    cout << ("El costo inicial de esta compra es: $") << endl;
    cout << costoTotal << endl;
    cout << ("El total del descuento que se le aplico es: $") << endl;
    cout << descTotal << endl;
    cout << ("El costo final de esta compra es: $") << endl;
    cout << costFinal << endl;
    return 0;
}
```